# Github Page, how to make my project site to use main site layout?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have an organization github page [www.spoonmangames.cl](http://www.spoonmangames.cl) and I created a project site called Unity3DTools so I can access this with [www.spoonmangames.cl/Unity3DTools/](http://www.spoonmangames.cl/Unity3DTools/)

So far so good, but I want my project site to use the layouts I've created in my organization page. I tried to just add `layout: default` in the front matter section of index.html in the project site but it just show a blank page with the title (you can actually check in the url above).

I do not want to copy stuff into the project site, is there any other solution?

By the way the project site has only the readme.md and index.html, maybe I should add a config.yml with some special configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to use [Jekyll themes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/themes/).

Answer (score 0):

If the two things we're talking about is this [main site](https://github.com/SpoonmanGames/spoonmangames.github.io) and this [subdirectory](https://github.com/SpoonmanGames/Unity3DTools/blob/master/index.html), then maybe jekyll doesn't really knows about your subdirectory so it doesn't try to serve it.

Have you tried to upload a `unity3dtools.md` (or ~.html) to main site's root directory and then permalink it to `/Unity3DTools` ?

The above could be one solution, but if you don't want to copy anything to the project site, maybe you should consider defining a new [collection](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) in the `_config` named something like "projects" and then each project you create, should contains a property "directory" which in this case points to the **/Unity3DTools** directory.

Try the following (be careful, try this first on your local development first)

```
collections:
  projects:
    output: true
```

Then make a `_projects` directory and make a `Unity3DTools.md` file with some of the followings:

```
---
name: Unity3DTools
permalink: /Unity3DTools
projectDir: Unity3DTools
[some extra stuff you want]
---
```

**I'm pretty sure this is not enough**, but maybe it helps your further research to accomplish. Share if you're moved ahead some steps!

Comment: Sadly this hasn't worked for me. If I managed to solve this issue I'll let you know, but I can't figure it out soon I will have to just copy stuff to get started with what I really want to do :(